# How to create angular modal popups for a loop of buttons

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, popup, angular9

I'm a beginner in angular and currently i'm working with angular 9.I have a task that creates a set of buttons using a loop as follows.

```
  <div class="play-game" [formGroup]="seatsFormGroup">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let seat of seats;let idx = index">
    <label>Seat {{seat.id}}</label>
    <input type="input"
           [value]=""
           formControlName="{{seat.name}}"
           />
    <button (click)="join(seat.id)">Join</button>
  </div>
```

I have a set of seats from 1-10 inside an array and the above code creates the set of buttons for each seat id.I need to add a modal popup for each button to display with the seat id when clicked. I tried the below code inside  but it always gave me only the last seat id(10) in every popup. Please help with a code.

```
      <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal" [style.display]="showModal ? 'block' : 'none'">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">{{seat.id}}</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="hide()">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="hide()">Dismiss</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: which library you are using for modal?

Comment: @AakashGarg I think its bootstarp. Does the library matter?

Comment: updated the answer below. the answer below is for ng-bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seat-modal-component.html

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" [style.display]="showModal ? 'block' : 'none'">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">{{seat.id}}</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="hide()">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="hide()">Dismiss</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

seat-modal.component.ts

```
export class SeatComponent {
   public seat;

}
```

**Component in which you have Loop 
HTML :-**

```
<div class="play-game" [formGroup]="seatsFormGroup">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let seat of seats;let idx = index">
    <label>Seat {{seat.id}}</label>
    <input type="input"
           [value]=""
           formControlName="{{seat.name}}"
           />
    <button (click)="join(seat)">Join</button>
  </div>
```

**TS :-**

```
public seatModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}
  public join(seat) {
    this.seatModalRef = this.modalService.open(SeatModalComponent);
    this.seatModalRef.componentInstance.seat = seat;
  }
```

Comment: can I create the modal inside where the button component is in without creating two components?

Comment: you can create it, but this way it will be better.

Comment: what is NgbModalService? Cannot import it

Comment: sorry its NgbModal not NgbModalService. Will change above.

Comment: I did this but the modal window does not pop up. Only a faded overlay is displayed instead.Why is that?

Comment: Is there a way that I can change my popup window position closer to the relevant button, like poping up from the button just like a callout?